# C# LINQ Lambda multiple group of IEnumerable with Sum()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, lambda

I have a collection of `data = IEnumerable<AnalyticsData>` and I'm trying to group by multiple properties and `Sum()` on an integer column. The end result will be a collection of `AnalyticsReportRow<dynamic>()` as you can see below, though this isn't highly relevant.

In the final `Select()` method, I want to pass an object in, ideally from the original set and would prefer not to recreate one in the middle of my chained queries if possible. Most of the examples seem like the create either a new strongly-typed or dynamic object to pass into the next link in the chain.

Here's what I have spent a few hours trying to work with, and this returns the set as it is in the first code block below with all rows (I export to CSV, hence the formatting):

```
var pageViewsData = analyticsData.GroupBy(data => new { g1 = data.Webproperty, pv = data.PageViews, d = data })
    .GroupBy(data => new { gg1 = data.Key.g1, dd = data.Key.d })
    .Select(data => new AnalyticsReportRow<dynamic>(data.Key.dd, "Page_Views", data.Sum(datas => datas.Key.pv)));
```

Result is this:

```
"CustomerA","","","","","Page_Views",0,"A1-810","","",2,"4/10/2015 16:08:33"
"CustomerA","","","","","Page_Views",0,"A1-810","","",2,"4/10/2015 16:08:33"
"CustomerA","","","","","Page_Views",0,"GT-N8013","","",2,"4/10/2015 16:08:33"
"CustomerA","","","","","Page_Views",0,"GT-P3113","","",7,"4/10/2015 16:08:33"
"CustomerA","","","","","Page_Views",0,"GT-P3113","","",2,"4/10/2015 16:08:33"
"CustomerA","","","","","Page_Views",0,"GT-P3113","","",3,"4/10/2015 16:08:33"
"CustomerA","","","","","Page_Views",0,"GT-P3113","","",3,"4/10/2015 16:08:33"
"CustomerA","","","","","Page_Views",0,"GT-P3113","","",2,"4/10/2015 16:08:33"
```

And would like to end up with a `Sum()` on the second-last column, grouped by customer and then by device. For example:

```
"CustomerA","","","","","Page_Views",0,"A1-810","","",4,"4/10/2015 16:08:33"
"CustomerA","","","","","Page_Views",0,"GT-N8013","","",2,"4/10/2015 16:08:33"
"CustomerA","","","","","Page_Views",0,"GT-P3113","","",16,"4/10/2015 16:08:33"
```

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the logic and could really use an example of how to group like this, even pseudocode and dynamic types.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours on this today, and posting my question, I decided to try a few more things and read some more documentation on `GroupBy()`.

As it turns out, I was missing the fact that you can provide a Key Selector and an Element Selector to the `GroupBy` method [as explained in the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534304%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If I understand correctly, this provides the ability to have a distinct qualifier that tells the query how to group.

In the end, this appears to give me what I need. I would really like some feedback on this to make sure I'm going about it correctly:

```
var pageViewsData = analyticsData.Where(data => data.PageViews > 0)
  .GroupBy(data => new { g1 = data.Webproperty, g2 = data.DeviceModel }, data => data)
  .Select(data => new AnalyticsReportRow<dynamic>(data.FirstOrDefault(), "Page_Views", data.Sum(d => d.PageViews)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var query = from d in analyticsData
            group d by new { d.Webproperty, d.DeviceModel }
            into g
            select new 
            {
                g.Webproperty,
                g.DeviceModel,
                Total = g.Sum(it => it.PageViews)
            };
var result = query.ToList();
```